# How to call a function from another function in a class in Python

Tags: python, oop

In the example below, How do I call `function 1` in `function 2`. I have tried it just like in the example, but does not recognise `para` in `function 2` and I have also tried replacing it with `self.para` which gets a undefined error..what is the right way to call `function 1`? I can't add another argument in `function2(self)`.

```
class Example:
    #def...

    def function1(self, para):
        #bla bla
    
    def function2(self):
        xxx = self.function1(para)
        # how do I call a function such as this
```

Comment: What argument do you want to pass to `para`? `self.function1(<that argument goes here>)`

Comment: What example are you referring to? What error do you see?

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Answer (score 3):

```
class Example:
    #def...

    def function1(self, para):
        #bla bla
    
    def function2(self):

        para = 12  # make sure the variable you pass to function1 is defined        

        xxx = self.function1(para)
        # how do I call a function such as this
```

You can only reference `self.para` if class Example has been instantiated and has an attribute called `para`.

If class `Example` has attributes that are static, you can reference those through an instance (self) or through the class.

Instantiating and referencing self:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):  # constructor method
        self.value = 12  # instance attribute

    def func1(self, parameter):
        # do stuff
        return ...

    def func2(self):
        x = func1(self.value)
```

or from static context:

```
class Example:

    value = 12  # class attribute

    def func1(self, parameter):
        # do stuff
        return ...

    def func2(self):
        x = func1(Example.value)
```